# Python and Selenium chrome mobile emulation problem

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, google-chrome, mobile, emulation

what's wrong with this code please solve it.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 375, "height": 812, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"
}

chrome = Options()
chrome.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome)
driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/")
```

However, nothing happens: my page is still a normal browser page, and I don't see it as a mobile page.

What is missing or wrong in my code

Comment: the code throws this error message:   `WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH.` Please see https://chromedriver.chromium.org/home

Answer (score 1):

atm your code doesn't even run as normal desktop web

> TypeError: WebDriver.**init**() got an unexpected keyword argument
> 'chrome_options'

this 'woks on my machine':

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options

mobile_emulation = {
    "deviceMetrics": { "width": 375, "height": 812, "pixelRatio": 3.0 },
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.2.1; en-us; Nexus 5 Build/JOP40D) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19"
}
chrome = Options()
chrome.add_experimental_option("mobileEmulation", mobile_emulation)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome)
driver.get("https://www.whatismybrowser.com/detect/what-is-my-user-agent/")
```

so the only change is in the line:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chrome)
```

from `chrome_options=chrome` to `options=chrome`

py 3.11.4, selenium 4.13, chrome 117.0.5938.149 (standalone chromedriver unnecessary since selenium 4.6).